# Работа с планировщиком задач

Tags: c#, cmd

Здравствуйте, как используя планировщик задач, создать задачу в определенной папке, что бы запускалась при входе в систему и каждые 5 минут.

Желательно через `cmd`, т.к. пробуя через библиотеку `Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler`

Делал так

```
//ts - TaskService
//Folder - {\Microsoft\Windows}
TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
td.RegistrationInfo.Author = "Microsoft";
td.RegistrationInfo.Version = new Version("1.0.0");
td.Triggers.Add(new LogonTrigger { Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30) });
td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(thisDirectory));
td.Principal.RunLevel = TaskRunLevel.Highest;
Folder.RegisterTaskDefinition(thisDirectory, td, TaskCreation.CreateOrUpdate, @"", null, TaskLogonType.S4U);//тут ошибка
```

Помогите создать задачу через `Schtasks`!

Comment: Ну окей, вы выполнили этот код, и что произошло?

Comment: @VladD Ошибка доступа. Но вопрос можно уже закрыть, т.к. реализовал через командную строку